# sklearn selectKbest: which variables were chosen?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get sklearn to select the best k variables (for example k=1) for a linear regression. This works and I can get the R-squared, but it doesn't tell me which variables were the best. How can I find that out?

I have code of the following form (real variable list is much longer):

```
X=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
X.append([averageindegree[i],indeg3_sum[i],indeg5_sum[i],indeg10_sum[i])


training=[]
actual=[]
counter=0
for fold in range(500):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = crossval.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
    clf = LinearRegression()
    #clf = RidgeCV()
    #clf = LogisticRegression()
    #clf=ElasticNetCV()

    b = fs.SelectKBest(fs.f_regression, k=1) #k is number of features.
    b.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #print b.get_params

    X_train = X_train[:, b.get_support()]
    X_test = X_test[:, b.get_support()]


    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    sc = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    training.append(sc)
    #print "The training R-Squared for fold " + str(1) + " is " + str(round(sc*100,1))+"%"
    sc = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    actual.append(sc)
    #print "The actual R-Squared for fold " + str(1) + " is " + str(round(sc*100,1))+"%"
```

Comment: `b.get_support()`, which you are already using, gives you a boolean mask of the selected features.

Comment: You're right, got it!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use get_support:

```
features_columns = [.......]
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=5)
print zip(fs.get_support(),features_columns)
```

Comment: Calling `fit()` function is missing? 

Answer (score 1):

Try using `b.fit_transform()` instead of `b.tranform()`. the `fit_transform()` function with fit and transform your input X to new X with selected features and return the new X.

```
...
b = fs.SelectKBest(fs.f_regression, k=1) #k is number of features.
X_train = b.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
#print b.get_params
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to configure SelectKBest with your favourite function (regression in your case), and then to get the params out of it.
My code assumes you have a list `features_list` that contains the names of all the headlines of X.

```
    kb = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=5) # configure SelectKBest
    kb.fit(X, Y)  # fit it to your data
    # get_support gives a vector [False, False, True, False....]
    print(features_list[kb.get_support()])
```

Certainly you can write it more pythonic than me :-)